# How to clean up and close app after being called through an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

We have an app that has a function using the Android share facility.  If a property listing is shared from the Rightmove app, our app takes that property and adds the details to our server-side database.  When the app is launched normally (not through share) it checks for updates on launch.

The app does what it is supposed to do when launched normally and also when launched by sharing from the Rightmove app.  Except in the latter case it continues to check for updates which is not supposed to do.

Here is the `onCreate()` method where all the relevant code resides:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent rightmove = getIntent();
    String action = rightmove.getAction();
    String type = rightmove.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        String rm_text = rightmove.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (rm_text.startsWith("I found this property on the Rightmove")) {
            String[] parts = rm_text.split("/");
            String rm_code = parts[parts.length - 1];

            new UpdateList().execute(rm_code);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Lets Delight only takes share information from the Rightmove app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        this.finish();
    }


    user    = findViewById(R.id.user);
    status  = findViewById(R.id.status);
    message = findViewById(R.id.message);

    Button dman = findViewById(R.id.button_decision);
    Button todo = findViewById(R.id.button_todo);

    new Update(status).check(this);
}
```

The `if` block for dealing with the share ends with `this.finish();` but the code continues after this and checks for updates.  It must therefore draw a UI that is not required or used.

Is it a case that `finish();` takes a while to complete and, whilst it is doing so, the code continues to execute or is something else happening here?  Either way, what is the "correct" way to handle having share information sent to an app that just processes that share data without presenting a UI to the user?

Comment: Just add an else { } block after the if and put the code you don't want executed if the statement is true in the else block.

Comment: Although that would solve the problem, is it really a good solution when there could be lots of code in the else{} block? It also doesn't answer why finish() is not terminating the app...

Comment: Activity.finish() does not terminate the activity right away. It starts the process of finishing the app, but the code after it may still get executed while the system is finishing the activity. To check if finish() has been called on activity, use isFinishing(). To answer your question about if it is a good solution, yes, it is. It's basically the best solution (or you could check if(!activity.isFinishing)) and put the code in the block. If you have a lot of code in it, separate it in different methods to improve readability, but the concept is the same.